# ListGrid column change event

Tags: smartclient

I have requirement to create a custom ListGrid, where user can show, hide, filter a column. also can change width and reOrder column and even color it and sort direction.
I know that list grid provide all this facility to user.

But I have to save all these changes and user will get this things back when they login again.

Is there any event which record all changes??
And how to get all this data from listGrid??

​Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ListGrid.viewStateChanged():

> Notification method executed whenever the viewState of this grid
>   changes. View state is accessible via ListGrid.getViewState(), and
>   contains field state information, sort information, selection
>   information, hiliting information and grouping information.

Comment: use FilterEditorSubmit() event to trace filter modification for each cell. ListGrid.FilterData() to filter explicitly and also can use ListGrid.getCriteria() to get applierd filter information or ListGrid.getFilterEditorCriteria() to get non-applied criteria information.